# How do I use regular javascript to look through every <a> tag and change the href?

Tags: javascript

A page has many  tags. How do I loop through all of them and replace their "href" with "http://example.com"?

(do not use jQuery)

Comment: Why do you want to not use jQuery?

Comment: @Anon: Because, believe it or not, you **must learn JavaScript** before using jQuery!

Comment: Because it's too heavy and too large of a file (20kb).  Every byte counts.

Comment: You are worried about 20kb? Are your users on 28.8k dialup or something?

Comment: @Andrew JavaScript != "traversing the DOM". I don't see any reason to learn about DOM traversal and other browser-specific APIs before learning jQuery.

Comment: If you're worried about size, use Google's CDN - it'll probably be faster than just about anything you've got, and there's a decent chance it'll already be in the browser's cache: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Mike If this is all he's doing, then yes - this'll be easier than pulling in jQuery. But it won't take too many more "little features" before the "coding without jQuery" will out weight the "cost of using jQuery".

Comment: @David: It sure is part of it... There are things you can do without a framework, it's unfortunate that everybody forgot that.

Comment: Indeed, this is relatively straightforward without a framework. But when the asker comes in and explicitly states that a framework should *not* be used, well, the reasons behind that restriction need to come out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); 
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
    links[i].href = "http://example.com";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `document.links` collection. It's defined by the W3C and supported by all common browsers.

Moreover you get access not only to `<a>` elements, but to `<area>` tags too  (which are commonly used in client image maps).

```
for(var i=0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
   document.links[i].href = "http://example.com";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) to fetch all the links, and then loop through them to change the `href` property.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

if(links) { // if none are found, do not continue
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].href = 'http://example.com/';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i=0;i<links.length;i++)
    links[i].href = "http://example.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i=0,L=document.links.length;i <L; i++) {
   document.links[i].href = "http://example.com";
}
```

Or load a 20 kb library and write a little less code.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is the same as a previous answer.